# Which NoSql solution should I choose?

Tags: database, nosql, bigdata

I'm having a system distributed on dozens of servers. It supposed to perform about 10000 reads and writes per second. The record size is about few KB. The data integrity is not very important. Which NoSql solution should I choose?

Thanks! 
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well.. that depends a great deal on the type of data you want to store, how you want to access it, etc.

Here is a comparison of the hottest contenders: http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis

For your needs, where data integrity is not of upmost importance you might want to try Redis. It is all in memory, making it blitz-fast, but with persistence to disk... it is not a database per se, though, but a key/value store, so you'll have to think a little different as to how to store and retrieve data, there are a number of good tutorials on this online...

Comment: I have a virtual CentOS machine running in Virtualbox (for development purposes), it has 1/4 of a Intel i5 340M cpu (roughly 700 cpu passmark score), running the redis benchmark with 3KB values yields 16k reads and 11k writes per second (of single values, if you organize data into lists write value is 21k writes). And redis easily handles master-slave replication (it's like one line in the config file or one command run on server...)